# How to model an error message without ending the activity process in an activity diagram with UML

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I am making an UML activity diagram. Now i have a situation that i have an Active and a Passive status within my data. The process needs to check the statusses and when there is a Passive status it should send an error message but also needs to continu with checking the data for both active and passive records.

So the maintenance team needs to be aware that there is data with status = passive but the process needs to continue 2/3 steps where data for both passive and active needs to be checked. After that 3th process only the active status needs to be checked further on.

How do i model this? Is it ok to use the activity final node? Or means that final node that the passive status will not be taken further in the process?

Thanks!

Comment: it seems you just need decisions nodes to do or not actions

Comment: Thabk you very much! I got stuck because i thought an errormessage should always end with an end node. But i can navigatr it back to the gateway. Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I well understand you just have something like that :

[image]

or if you prefer :

[image]

in both cases when the final node is reach the execution is done

Comment: hi Bruno, why don't you use an initial final node instead of the final node?

Comment: @KeesLasser I do not understand you, an initial node cannot be the target of a flow, and a final node cannot start a flow. There is nothing before an initial node, and there is nothing after a final node, this is why there are named initial and final

Comment: Excuse me i said it wrong. Why don't you use a flow final node instead of the activity final node? THank you

Comment: @KeesLasser a flow final node can be used when you have fork and some branch(es) finish by it letting other branch(es) continuing, but here there is no fork. The fact the activity finishes does not means the process/thread supporting its execution is done. Why do you wanted to use a flow final rather than the final node ?

Comment: Ok, i thought when i use a final node the complete activity diagram stops. And when i use a flow final node then the process continues with the status=active (ref. to your first diagram)

Comment: @KeesLasser my 2 diagrams are equivalent. Why do you want the activity continues ? to do what after "other steps" I put to do all necessary in case of active status ? Note an activity is a behavior and can model for instance the body of an operation, and an operation as an activity is not a process.

Comment: I want that it continues because it's the end of a 'passive' status but we want to continue with the 'Active' status. Maybe i don't understand the difference between the flow final node and the activity final node.

Comment: @KeesLasser how many data having a status the activity manages at a time ? I supposed one. If they are possibly several at a time the activity must be changed and for instance the guard `status = Passive`must be replaced by `at least a data as the status passive` etc, is it what you want ?

Comment: For example it is a file with 10 rows with 7 active and 3 passive. What woukd you do then?